# Pull the Server out of Cluster in Advance to Reduce Response Time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, cluster-computing

Besides JAVA_OPTS tuning,I have another idea about reducing the RT(Response Time).I wonder is there any company or project using this ?

The final goal of JAVA_OPTS tuning is reduce the RT.While the full gc with CMS(Concurrent Mark Sweep) is unavoidable sometime,why can't pull the server out of the cluster in advance ?
For example,we use code to recognize the old space's usage rate.When the rate is over 60%,this server notifies the load balance to pull it out,then invokes `java.lang.System.gc()`,after this notifies the load balance again to pull it in.
[image: load balance]
Is this way ok?

Comment: Sounds good. But keep close eye on situation when multiple servers simultaneously request LB to be detached, or you may end up with no servers to handle requests. (Some malformed or super heavy request or burst of requests may disable servers one by one). And, if you can afford, it seems to me that restart of the server is cleaner than just full GC.

Comment: Thx for your acceptance .The LB will judge when receives a pull out proposal. `if(numberOfPulledOut>threshold) {reject this proposal and not pull it out }`.
As for restart ,the initialization usually costs much time and CPU resource .